# solve $XA = B$ in MATLAB

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, singularity, inverse-problems

I have an equation $XA = B$ in which $X$ and $B$ are $n \times m$  and $A$ is $m \times m$. And $n>m$ .  $A$ is positive definite. How to calculate $X$. I used $X = B / A$  in MATLAB. but it compute the warning that:  Matrix is close to singular...

my question is that which matrix is close to singular? $A$ or $B$?

And
My second is how to solve it by regularization?

I find some MATLAB toolbox solve those problem by regularization:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/52-regtools
such as its function
function [x_lambda,rho,eta] = tikhonov(U,s,V,b,lambda,x_0)

it solves $Ax = b$
But I don't know how to use it to $XA=B$.

Thanks

Comment: I would do: $A^TX^T = B^T$, then transpose the solution.

Comment: Conceptually, you are multiplying both sides of the equation by $A^{-1}$ on the right.  (That's where the use of slash (`mrdivide`) comes from.)  Hence the matrix that is close to singular is $A$.